# Woocommerce checkout field keep change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use this code to change my checkout field layout, with Woocommerce Checkout shortcode that I put inside product page [woocommerce_checkout] it's look good but not in checkout page, it's change back to original after 1 second. I try change theme and disable all plugin except Woocommerce, still happen. How to fix this issue?

```
/**
 Remove all possible fields
 **/
function wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
echo '<style>       
.woocommerce-additional-fields {
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce-checkout #customer_details>* {
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}
</style>';
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['priority'] = 10;
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'Name';
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['class'] = array( 'form-row-wide' );

$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 20;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Address';

$fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 30;
$fields['billing']['billing_country']['label'] = 'Country';
$fields['billing']['billing_country']['class'] = array( 'form-row-first' );

$fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 40;
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['label'] = 'State';
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['class'] = array( 'form-row-last' );

$fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 50;
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = 'City';
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['class'] = array( 'form-row-first' );

$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 60;
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['label'] = 'Postcode';
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['class'] = array( 'form-row-last' );

$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 70;
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Phone';
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array( 'form-row-first' );

$fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 80;
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = 'Email';
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array( 'form-row-last' );

unset( $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'] );
unset( $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] );
unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
unset( $fields['order']['order_comments'] );

return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_checkout_fields' );
```

[image]
with shortcode and first view at checkout page

[image]
Change after 1 second at checkout page

[image]
After disable javascript on browser

Comment: try: disabling JavaSript on your browser, and, looking at the network tab in your browsers dev tools as the page is loading to see if the change in appearance coincides with the loading of a CSS or JS file or an XHR request - we don't have enough information to solve this problem and I don't think it's a PHP issue

Comment: I disable Javascript on my chrome, and it's look like what I want. Need to fiqure out which javascript change back my new layout field. I think it's from default woocommerce itself

Answer (score 0):

I try remove wc-checkout script with this and the layout become what I want

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_woocommerce_checkout_scripts', 9999 );
function remove_woocommerce_checkout_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
}
```